# Decouple task from UI thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I found the following code somewhere:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

coroutineScope.launch {
    withContext (
        context = Dispatchers.IO,
        block = block)
}
```

I am wondering, if there is a difference to the following code:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

coroutineScope.launch (
    context = Dispatchers.IO,
    block = block)
```

Comment: Good question, it asks nuanced behaviour of kotlin coroutines. It seems should not have a difference in behaviour, but I can not say for sure. Subscribed to your question to learn more.

Comment: Same behavior, but bytecode might be different and less efficient.